# perl regex matching vowels and consonants

Tags: regex, perl

I want a regular expression to match a word that has at least 3 vowels in it that are separated by consonants. For example a words like *general and overflow* would match. The following is what I came up with but it is not working.

```
    / ([^aeiou])([aeiou])\g1\g2\g1\g2\w*/
```

Comment: That's not a very good definition of vowel (e.g. "naïve", "Noël") or of consonant (e.g. includes hyphens).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\g1` aka `\1` matches what was captured. So what you have there will match `xoxoxo` but not `xoxoxa`

I'd simply use

```
/[aeiou](?:[^aeiou]+[aeiou]){2}/
```

But if you wanted to avoid the repetition, you have options.

```
my $vowel     = qr/[aeiou]/;
my $consonant = qr/[^aeiou]/;
/$vowel (?: $consonant+ $vowel ){2}/x
```

```
/
   (?&VOWEL) (?: (?&CONSONANT)+ (?&VOWEL) ){2}
   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<VOWEL>     [aeiou]  )
      (?<CONSONANT> [^aeiou] )
   )
/x
```

Comment: @NigoroJr, Thanks, though I cleaned up the edit. It makes no sense to use `?`, and the `+` doesn't belong inside the definition of a consonant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use this:

```
$ echo 'general overflow of redundancy a#a#a, Xoxoxo!'|perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while
>  m/([a-z]*[aeiou](?:[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+[aeiou]){2}[a-z]*)/ig'
general
overflow
redundancy
Xoxoxo
$
```

---

For comparison - below are the samples of how **incorrect answers** behave:

```
$ echo 'general overflow of redundancy a#a#a, Xoxoxo!'|perl -ne 'print "$1\n"
>  while m/([aeiou](?:[^aeiou][aeiou]){2})/ig'
enera
a#a#a
oxoxo
$ echo 'general overflow of redundancy a#a#a, Xoxoxo!'|perl -ne 'print "$1\n"
>  while m/([aeiou](?:[^aeiou]+[aeiou]){2})/ig'
enera
overflo
of redu
ancy a#a
a, Xoxo
$
```